# I want to post a list of object in a json body element

Tags: python, json, api, post, request

I want to make a post request with one of the element containing a list of key values with several objects in it. However when I put the JSON data in my request body, the element puts ' ' around the whole list making it not serializable for the web server that will receive the data.

```
// the format should be like this ->{
"data1": str, 
"data2": int, 
"devices": {
    "device1": [ 
        {
            "timestamp": int, 
            "temperature": int 
        },
        ... // More signals from same device
    ], 

    ... // More devices for example device 2 same format etc.
}
```

}

However when I run my code with the same format I end up with this output

```
{'data1': '1234', 'data2': 1234, 'devices': {'"device1": [{"temperature": 20, "timestamp": 1585776505}]}, {"device2": [{"temperature": 18, "timestamp": 1585776505}]'}} ///etc..
```

As you can see inside devices element it's an " ' " at the begining and at the end that ruins the format so the web server cant receive the data. I don't know how to get rid of it. When I don't put the the data in the request body the format looks good the " ' " is not there. I use python first by making a dictionary that I put in a list with all of the devices I receive and then I put them in to the request body after using `json.dumps()`.

```
        mac_dict2 = {devicename: 
        [{"temperature" : temp, 
        "timestamp": int(time.time())}]
        } // the format i want my list of devices to have



        mac_list.append(mac_dict2) // mac_list is an empty list that gets filled with the devices
        if item == device_data[-1]: //an if statement that will fill my last index in the list with all the devices that i want send forward to the webserver
            print("MAC LIST------------>")

            print("JSON LIST------------>")
            new_mac_json = json.dumps(mac_list)
            final_list = new_mac_json[2:-2] / i use this function to erase the bars from the list 
            print("NEW LIST------------>")
            print(final_list )

            json_obj_go = {
            "data1": str,
            "data2": int(time.time()),
            "devices": {final_list // i put the list inside of the json body
            }
        }
            print("JSON OBJ------------>")
            print(json_obj_go)
```

**The output looks almost well its just the " ' " which ends up before and after the final list in the request body. As i said before i want the devices element to have seperate devices inside contains their own specific values/data inside an array**

Comment: `json.dumps` do convert your data into `str`. You shouldn't dump it if you want don't want string data.

Comment: Yes i know but if I use it as a list i cant remove the brackets [ ] which i dont want in the format. Which is why i convert it to string so i can remove the brackets however it receives ' ' instead ...Is their anyway to fix this format ive tried the most?

Comment: Why do you want to remove brackets(`[]`)? It is JSON format.

Comment: Because then i get an bracket over all the data after devces element like this sir -> 'devices': [{'"device1": [{"temperature": 20, "timestamp": 1585776505}]}, {"device2": [{"temperature": 18, "timestamp": 1585776505}]}]}, which i dont want because the webserver denies the data then :/ i have to somewhat remove the brackets without turning it to string.

Comment: Then what is your expected data structure?

Comment: i think i need to put devices element as a dict with separate devices objects that contain their own list, somehow?